# Removing items from ListActivity with custom listadapter containing checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listactivity

I am trying to remove the list items from listactivity which has custom list adapter. Custom list adapter has textviews and checkboxes. When user selects the items by clicking on checkboxes, a button appears in the bottom of screen and on clicking on button, i want to delete the items from the adapter. I have implemented the solution by setting the position as a tag to checkbox but its not working. Checked positions and listview indices are not mapped correctly. I am posting my code here:

## ListAdapter

```
<code>

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gmail_list_layout, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.checkView = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_content);
        viewHolder.fromView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from_content);
        viewHolder.subjectView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject_content);
        viewHolder.rootLayout = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rootGmail);

        Log.i("mustang", "Adding view at Position: " + position);
        viewHolder.checkView.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.checkView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);    
    }


OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Integer position = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
            Log.i("mustang", "Position: " + position);
            if(isChecked)
            {
                checkedPositions.put(position, position);
                buttons.put(position, buttonView);
            }
            else
            {
                checkedPositions.remove(position);
                buttons.remove(position);
            }

            Log.i("mustang", "Positions Array: " + checkedPositions.size());
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>(checkedPositions.values());
            context.itemsSelected(positions);
        }
    };



     public ArrayList<Integer> getCheckedPositions()
     {
return  new ArrayList<Integer>(checkedPositions.values());
        }

</code>
```

Whenever checkbox is selected, button appears in bottom to remove the items. Button showing code and removal code is shown here:

Showing button when items selected by checkboxes are more than one:

```
<code>
public void itemsSelected(ArrayList<Integer> positions)
    {
        Log.i("mustang", "positions.size(): " + positions.size());
        deleteItemsButton.setText("Delete " + positions.size() + " mails?");
        deleteItemsButton.setVisibility(positions.size() > 0 ? Button.VISIBLE : Button.INVISIBLE);
    }

</code>
```

And when user clicks on it following code runs:

```
<code>
private OnClickListener deleteItemsListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = emails.getCheckedPositions();

            for(Integer p : positions)
            {
                emails.remove(emails.getItem(p.intValue()));
            }


            emails.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
</code>
```

Please point me out that I am implementing the technique in the right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what is not working, or what you mean by `not mapped correctly`

Comment: When i selects the items at indices 1,2 and then clicks on delete button then wrong positioned items are deleted plus checkbox remained selected after notifyDataSetChanged called on adapter.

Comment: and by `the wrong`, you mean which ones ?

Comment: Actually random positioned element is removed. Actually i think that when i notifiy datasetchanged, then items are refreshed but redrawing is not done which means items' position is pointing to the old data rather than new positions.

Comment: you don't need to `notifyDataSetChanged`, as you remove directly from the adapter. post the code where you create the adapter, as the underlying data may be manipulated somewhere else.

Comment: this function is called in onCreate() menthod which passes an array of objects. function is public void emailsFetched(Message[] objects) 
 {
  messges = new ArrayList<Message>();
  
  emailListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  emails = new GMailAdapter(this, messges);
  emailListView.setAdapter(emails);
 }

Comment: @njzk2 when to use notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: do you ever modify the `messages` list ?

Comment: no i do not modify the list after creating adapter.